# O que seria a Linguagem Zig?

Tags: terminologia, característica-linguagem, design-de-linguagem, zig

- O que é Zig? E para que serve?
- É uma nova versão do Rust?
  Pois parece muito com Rust. É um clone?
- É melhor que C/C++?

Comment: Se a pergunta estiver mal formulada, além da nota negativa favor, tente ao menos alegar sobre, para que possa ser melhorado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> O que é Zig? E para que serve?

**Zig** é uma linguagem programação com multi-paradigmas, desenvolvido por Andrew Kelley nos meados 2015/2016 como Hobby (alega o autor), tendo a pretensão de se tornar uma alternativa a linguagem C.
Embora a sintaxe lembre bastante **Rust** e **Go**, possui também características semelhantes a linguagem C com gerenciamento de memória manual, porém não possui uma forma padrão para tal (o programador terá de escolher qual alocador utilizará) e segue os conceitos da linguagem **Jai** (linguagem de programação - piloto [nunca foi lançado] idealizado por Jonathan Blow).

Assim como a linguagem **Go**, tanto a linguagem quanto o compilador compartilham o mesmo nome. O compilador é uma variante do compilador Clang "fork" [suportando compilação cruzada] do projeto LLVM com sistema de caching nativo, ou seja, não precisará utilizar `ccache` ou similar. Então é possível compilar também projetos C com `zig cc` e C++ com `zig c++` (quando utilizo num projeto com CMake por exemplo, detecta o executável `zig` como Clang compiler).

> É uma nova versão do Rust? É melhor que C/C++?

Não! É uma linguagem nova, trazendo novas abordagens inspiradas em outras linguagens, como Rust e Go.
Se ser melhor signifique desempenho e/ou segurança, não. Mas se for legibilidade e praticidade, então sim. Pois assim como C, o Zig tenta se manter minimalista nas quantidades de recursos, ao contrário do C++ e Rust e suas diversas abstrações. Pode entender melhor [aqui](https://ziglang.org/pt/learn/why_zig_rust_d_cpp/).

Poderia afirmar, nesse caso que:

> *É mais fácil recompilar qualquer projeto C/C++ com Zig, do que reescrevê-lo em Rust ou qualquer outra linguagem.*

**Mais informações:**

- [site oficial](https://ziglang.org/pt)
- [wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zig_(linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o))
- [ZigLearn](https://ziglearn.org) - Documentação *não-oficial* (inglês)